# Python, add variable index to dbm.dumb module

Tags: python, string, variables, dbm

I'm having issues adding an index variable to dbm.dumb. What i mean by index variable:

```
var = b"string",b"string_one",b"string_two"
var[0] #being an index variable
```

Now when I try and add to it using the following code:

```
database = dbm.dumb.open(z ,'c')


database["item 1"] = x[2],y[2]
database["item 2"] = x[0],y[0]
database["item 3"] = x[1],y[1]
```

and i get the following error

```
TypeError: values must be bytes or strings
```

I have tried casting the variables so they are strings but it wont let that go through. I'm stuck.

Comment: Use the `type` command to test your variables. `var` is a tuple, `var[0]` is a string, which is expected as input. But you are entering two strings separated by a comma. That's not a string.

Answer (score 0):

[`dbm`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html) is not he best lib to use in your case. [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) will solve your problem.

```
import shelve

database = shelve.open('/tmp/test.db', 'c')
database['item 1'] = [1, 2, 3]
database['item 2'] = 'string values'
database['item 3'] = {'name': 'Michael', 'lastname': 'Corbett'}
```

Comment: Issue with that is i have ti use dbm